# CV2 find object in image without matchTemplate

Tags: python, opencv

I'm asking for help finding a different solution to locate an object with a background full of other items (some of which having the same color as the object).

Example:

[image: like this]

I've tested it with the CV2 match template, but its accuracy is not that good when the object is bigger or smaller than the provided template, besides the time that it takes to analyze it, so I tried a different solution. I'm using the `inRange` and I've created a mask for the object that I'm looking for:

```py
def get_bl_titan_mask(img):
    axe = cv2.inRange(img, (78, 90, 92), (82, 92, 94)) + cv2.inRange(img, (27.43.43), (29.47.50))
    helmet = cv2.inRange(img, (70,70,53), (71, 71, 54)) + cv2.inRange(img, (95,94,70), (100, 98, 72))
    spikes = cv2.inRange(img, (185,177,160), (196,185,177))
    shoulders = cv2.inRange(img, (32, 32, 0), (45, 45, 22)) + cv2.inRange(img, (127,119.94),(134,125,101))
    shoulders = cv2.inRange(img, (32, 35, 0), (45, 45, 22)) + cv2.inRange(img, (127,119.94),(134,125,101))
    arms = cv2.inRange(img, (170, 193, 201), (180, 200, 207))
    chest_button = cv2.inRange(img, (159, 225, 242), (170, 244, 255))
    legs = cv2.inRange(img, (171,194,187),(180,199,206))
    foots = cv2.inRange(img, (46,46,31), (50,49,34))
    chest = cv2.inRange(img, (129, 155, 160 ), (140, 165, 169))
    shadow = cv2.inRange(img, (28.59.84), (40.63.90))
    return ax + helmet + spikes + shoulders + arms + chest_button + legs + foots + chest
```

and then I run a loop to try to find the object according to the mask:

```py
while True:
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(1460,150,1870,890))
    img_cv = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    mask = get_bl_titan_mask(img_cv)

    if cv2.countNonZero(mask) in range(750, 2500):
        print('there is a titan!')
        break
```

This way, I can search faster, but I have some issues with some false positives. If I have some of the mask colors in the background, it may consider that it is the object that I'm looking for. 
I tried to tune the range to try to increase the accuracy, but if the object is too small or too big, it can run out of the pixel range and it finds nothing.

I think this process of creating the mask is too complex and it may fail. Did you guys have some suggestions?

EDIT:
here are some samples of the mask with good results and false positives:

Good sample 1:

[image: good sample 1]

Good sample 2:

[image: good sample 2]

False positive:

[image: false positive]

Comment: Can you show me the results and the source images?

Comment: hi @Nikita I added in the original post :)

Comment: how do humans even see anything in those pictures? all I see is a low-resolution mess of neon color. you will need deep learning, or you need to hook into the game process to write your cheat.

Comment: @cristoph-rackwitz i would love to get into the game process to make some changes but i have no knowledge for it :(, but i agree with you, this game doesn't have the best graphics in the world :D